# Change default wordpress FS owner

Tags: wp-config, wp-filesystem

is it possible to change the default fs owner for wordpress? In our shared dev environment, we don't have access to the `www-data` user. Files created by wordpress under wp-content have the owner www-data as they are created by the php/apache2 process.

What I found so far is this:

```
define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', ( 0755 & ~ umask() ) ); 
define( 'FS_CHMOD_FILE', ( 0644 & ~ umask() ) );
```

All users are in the www-data usergroup but I don't really want to set it to 775. I'd like to set a different default owner instead.

Comment: Answer short, yes. It is actually a server question but that you know?! `chown -R yourname:www-data foldername` `chmod -R g+s foldername` and  about the chmod, I have non at 755 but that personally. [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) information.

Comment: @Charles I am looking to get wordpress to do the chown. I can't do it manually myself after the file was created as I don't have the permissions.